# Aperiodic tile with rational area

Tags: co.combinatorics, mg.metric-geometry, discrete-geometry, hyperbolic-geometry, tiling

Margulis and Mozes constructed aperiodic tiling system on the hyperbolic plane consisting of a single tile(hyperbolic polygon) whose area (or each inner angle) is irrational multiple of $\pi$. Having area irrational multiple of $\pi$ is not a necessary condition. So my question is, is there an aperiodic single tile whose area (or each angles)is rational multiple of $\pi$ ?

Comment: I believe the binary tiling is aperiodic and its tiles can be arbitrarily wide (and thus the area can be arbitrary)? Or did I miss any requirements?

Comment: @Zeno, by single tile I meant a hyperbolic polygon whose sides are geodesic segements.  The pentagon used in binary tiling is not really a hyperbolic one.

Comment: The simplest binary tiling has horocyclic segments indeed, but you can replace them with geodesic segments (i.e., connect their endpoints with a geodesic instead) and it still works.

Comment: Or if you don't need convexity, you could replace them with "puzzle piece polylines" which match in only the way you want, for a simple proof.

Comment: Thanks @zeno! what if we ask for only convex polygons?

Comment: I think the convex polygons (obtained by replacing the geodesic segments with straight lines, possibly also slanting the "vertical" segments) should work (except some specific cases where the apeirogons composed from all tiles at level $\leq k$ have angles $2\pi/n$ and thus tile the hyperbolic plane), but I do not see how to prove that the tiles cannot be tiled in any unintended way without boring case-by-case analysis.